# Angular 6 getting object error during build production

Tags: build, angular6

I have a working angular application on my development it works fine but whenever I am trying to build site for production I am getting this error:

```
 ERROR in src/app/agriculture/agriculture.component.html(20,61): : Property 'districts' does not exist on type '{}'.
src/app/agriculture/agriculture.component.html(27,60): : Property 'years' does not exist on type '{}'.
src/app/agriculture/agriculture.component.html(35,64): : Property 'view' does not exist on type '{}'.
src/app/agriculture/agriculture.component.html(41,64): : Property 'rain_fall_type' does not exist on type '{}'.
src/app/agriculture/agriculture.component.html(48,68): : Property 'Comparison' does not exist on type '{}'.
src/app/agriculture/agriculture.component.html(20,61): : Property 'districts' does not exist on type '{}'.
src/app/agriculture/agriculture.component.html(27,60): : Property 'years' does not exist on type '{}'.
src/app/agriculture/agriculture.component.html(35,64): : Property 'view' does not exist on type '{}'.
src/app/agriculture/agriculture.component.html(41,64): : Property 'rain_fall_type' does not exist on type '{}'.
src/app/agriculture/agriculture.component.html(48,68): : Property 'Comparison' does not exist on type '{}'.
```

I am using an object inside component :

```
data = {};
```

And inside my html my code is:

```
 <div class="col-sm-2">
      <select class='select-option' required [(ngModel)]='data.years' name="years">
       <option [ngValue]="undefined" disabled  selected> Views  </option>
       <option class='option' *ngFor='let option of views' [ngValue]="option">{{option}}</option>
      </select>
</div>
```

How to fix this and why I am not getting any error in development mode.

in my component I am using this array to loop:

```
  views = ["Graph", "Trend Line","Map View","Table"];
```

Comment: maybe you are receiving a different data response from server?

Comment: I don't understand why is it working in development mode. What should I do is this a bug

Comment: have you checked that you receive the same response structure both into development mode and into production mode?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem to your solution is very simple your data object is not defined this is the reason you are getting this error.

I had faced similar problem I was doing same mistake which you have done. You need to just add this to your data object:

```
 data: any = {};
```

This will solve your problem.